# classes in obj.c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> @interface MainViewController : UIViewController < FlipsideViewControllerDelegate >{
>   }

I am quite new to object oriented languages & especially obj.c.

I need to use addressbook framework within this class.Apple documentation suggests this code:

> @interface ViewController : UIViewController  < ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate > {}

I was wondering how to use at the same time FlipSideControllerDelegate & ABPeoplePickerControllerDelegate.

In fact I really can't understand what i am doing:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare your class as conforming to both the `FlipsideViewControllerDelegate` and the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` protocols like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate,
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> {}
```

Then implement the required methods in `MainViewController`'s `@implementation`.